# Java Script Display Hidden Field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with some options in HTML and what I am trying to do is for every different selected option I want to "Unhide" or display another set of options. Hopefully that makes sense. So I have a drop down options like `1`, `2` if user select option, i.e. `1`, I want to display another drop down menu.

The issue is that upon selection the 2nd drop down menu does not show at all.

The HTML:

```
  <select id="workshop" name="workshop" onclick="return test();">
                <option value="">Please select a Workshop</option>
                <option value="f">1</option>
                <option value="b">2</option>
            </select>

            <select id="date" name="date" style="display: none">
                <option value="">Please select a date</option>
                <option value="01/01/01">01/01/01 at 6.30pm</option>
            </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function test(){
   if(document.getElementById('workshop').value == 'f'){
      document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('date').style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all Use `onchange` event instead of using `onclick`. because `onchange` event occurs when the value of an element has been changed(As your requirement).

Try with this code:

```
function test(){
   if(document.getElementById('workshop').value == 'f'){
      document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

[Try in Js FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9tEN/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){
    if(document.getElementById('workshop').value == 'Forex'){
    document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'inline-block';//try this
}else{
    document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution to this problem by replacing onclick with onchange but still the problems remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `onclick` event. Use `onchange`:

```
<select id="workshop" name="workshop" onchange="return test();">
   <option value="">Please select a Workshop</option>
   <option value="f">1</option>
   <option value="b">2</option>
</select>

<select id="date" name="date" style="display: none">
   <option value="">Please select a date</option>
   <option value="01/01/01">01/01/01 at 6.30pm</option>
</select>
```

Onclick works well with buttons, but any kind of input reacts better on change. I bet it shows up the second time you click on the first select.

PS: Text inputs and textareas work even better when checking `onkeyup` or `onkeydown`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution to this problem by replacing onclick with onchange but still the problems remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use onchange

**HTML**

```
<select id="leave" onchange="test()">
  <option value="">Please select a Workshop</option>
  <option value="f">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function test()
    {
     if(document.getElementById('workshop').value == 'f')
     {
       document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'block';
     }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('date').style.display = '';
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

OKkkkk Hello people I found the issue, What happens is that I had my HTML & JS files both opened form different directories :D So the changes I was making to my JS file did not affect the HTML file which i was oppening in the browser. Really sorry for my mistake guys everyone up 1